# My ActiveX ComboBox changes dimensions

Tags: vba, excel, combobox

So I have a ComboBox set up that I have formatted in a way that allows it to be legible when the sheet is at 50% Zoom (it would be helpful to keep this is mind because other wise I would just be using data validation). This worked well for me except when I remove my laptop from its desktop dock. When I remotely access my companies network from the laptop, every time I click the dropdown box it changes the dimensions. I tried selecting "Move and Size with Cells" from the format control and this maintained the dimensions but would change the font size when I clicked the dropdown. None of these issues occur when I am attached to my desktop dock but I have to find a solution because the workbook will be accessed by many user that may need to use it while on a laptop once it is put into production.

Does anyone know a workaround or code that can solve this problem? If not, does anyone know what the root of the problem could be so I can experiment myself?

Thanks!

Comment: Combo box or dropdown box?? Not sure if there are properties tied to either that regulates size/formatting...

Comment: Don't use an ActiveX Combobox :) This is a known issue that's been around at least since Excel 2003.

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1573349/excel-the-incredible-shrinking-and-expanding-controls and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9518002/excel-vba-combobox-dropdown-button-size-changed-itself

Comment: Is there any work around for my main issue? A dropdown that the font size is legible at 50% zoom. As far as I know there is no way to edit font size with a form control or with data validation...