# Is there a simple way to change the caption of an ActiveX command button in VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

I have found these other questions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10641683/change-name-of-activex-command-button-using-vba-in-excel) [and here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37977889/excel-vba-to-change-the-caption-on-an-excel-command-button) which were a little too advanced. I just need a simple way to change the caption of an ActiveX command button "CommandButton1" when running a VBA code. I'm pretty sure it can be done way simpler than the other examples?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it can get much simpler than this:

```
Sub test()
Dim sht As Worksheet
Set sht = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Name of your Worksheet") 'the worksheet in which the button is located
sht.OLEObjects("Name of your Command Button").Object.Caption = "test"
End Sub
```

Answer (score 5):

For code not running in the sheet module ( `Sheet1` is the sheet [Code Name](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52721327/1383168) ) :

```
Sheet1.CommandButton1.Caption = "Text"
```

For code running in the sheet module, the `Sheet1.` part is not needed.