# Dynamically add toggle button to sheet and change it's name

Tags: excel, vba, spreadsheet

I'm using the code below to add a toggle button to sheet. I will need to dynamically re-create a sequence of buttons, and give them name and caption.

Can anyone help me with a way to change the caption/text of the toggle button button added using VBA? The bName will change so I will need a way to reference them by name.

```
Set Bttn = ActiveSheet.OLEObjects.Add(ClassType:="Forms.ToggleButton.1", Link:=False, _
                DisplayAsIcon:=False, Left:=R.Left, Top:=R.Top, Width:=R.Width, Height:=R.Height)
With Bttn
    .Name = bName
End With
```

where R is the target cell where button will be added

I tried the following, and they all error out:

```
Bttn.caption = bText
ActiveSheet.Shapes(bName).Text = bText
```

Comment: If you're getting errors it's useful to say what those errors are.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this workaround here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37978572/9852011

Not sure why you need to do this exactly but this code should work for you:

```
Dim Bttn As OLEObject, aButton As Variant

Set Bttn = ActiveSheet.OLEObjects.Add(ClassType:="Forms.ToggleButton.1", Link:=False, _
                DisplayAsIcon:=False, Left:=R.Left, Top:=R.Top, Width:=R.Width, Height:=R.Height)
With Bttn
    .Name = bName
End With

Set aButton = Bttn.Object
aButton.Caption = "whateverYouWant"
```

Answer (score 2):

Or, simply . . .

```
With Bttn
    .Name = bName
    .Object.Caption = "MyCaption"
End With
```