# Group radio buttons on Excel

Tags: excel, radio-button

I have two groups of radio buttons on the same Excel worksheet that I want them to work exclusively from each other.

I tried to search online for answers, and got to know there was GroupName Property which can be used to group the radio buttons, however, I haven't been able to locate this property.

Can anyone tell me how to find it?
There is only object positioning under the property tab of the format control window.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a *group box* control and then insert the radio buttons into that group box.

See here for more info: [Add a group box or frame control to a worksheet](https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/Add-a-group-box-or-frame-control-to-a-worksheet-fe867dbb-a98d-4d26-ae00-01f26b8c81b0)

Answer (score 0):

Use ActiveX controls
[image]

and in developer mode right click on RadioButton

[image]

and in properties box
[image]

Comment: Many user's computers by default won't trust ActiveX. So I would stay away from ActiveX if possible. And you can use a normal form control if you use group boxes. Also see [What is the difference between “Form Controls” and “ActiveX Control” in Excel 2010?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15455179/what-is-the-difference-between-form-controls-and-activex-control-in-excel-20)