# Excel macro properties menu?

Tags: excel

*Excel 2010* :

1) [image]
Excel Macro contains "Properties,View Code and CommandButton Object menus on right click.

2) [image]
Same Excel Macro does not show "Properties,View Code and CommandButton Object menus on right click.
What is the reason,not showing menus.How to get this properties.I would have tried to changing excel properties.

Answer (score 0):

There are two different kinds of [controls](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Overview-of-forms-Form-controls-and-ActiveX-controls-on-a-worksheet-15BA7E28-8D7F-42AB-9470-FFB9AB94E7C2) possible in an `Excel` worksheet.
Both can be inserted via developer tab:

[image]

Your first one is an [ActiveX control](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Overview-of-forms-Form-controls-and-ActiveX-controls-on-a-worksheet-15BA7E28-8D7F-42AB-9470-FFB9AB94E7C2#bmactivex_controls_on_the_control_toolb).

Your second one is an [Form control](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Overview-of-forms-Form-controls-and-ActiveX-controls-on-a-worksheet-15BA7E28-8D7F-42AB-9470-FFB9AB94E7C2#bmcontrols_on_the_forms_toolbar).

See also: [What is the difference between "Form Controls" and "ActiveX Control" in Excel 2010?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15455179/what-is-the-difference-between-form-controls-and-activex-control-in-excel-20)