# Checkbox in Excel is affecting a non-linked cell

Tags: excel, checkbox

I have a column of 67 checkboxes in an Excel sheet. All checkboxes link to the cell they are placed upon, so that TRUE/FALSE is written to this cell. However three of my checkboxes are also changing the value in an adjacent cell, and I cannot see how.

Interestingly, it changes the value of the adjacent cell, but the checkbox sitting on top of that adjacent cell doesn't toggle. Any ideas?

[image: Image of checkboxes and values in their linked cells]

Comment: [What kind](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15455179/11683) of checkboxes are they? Are you saying setting one checkbox changes two cells, or just one wrong cell? Are there formulas in the cells?

Comment: They are all Form Control Checkboxes. Yes, setting one checkbox changes two cells. Even though only one cell is specified in the 'linked cell' property. Ie: it changes the correct cell, but also the one adjacent. Note that it only happens for three checkboxes in the middle, not all 67! I have deleted those three and re-added them to the group control, same problem.
Is there a way I can share the excel - or is that against Stack Overflow policy?

Comment: Have placed the excel file in my google drive folder here: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1z3NHt_AlPDDVzPafC4spmrqOUWDuXj_X/edit?usp=sharing&ouid=117418988964498801208&rtpof=true&sd=true
I have placed comments in column O to tag the three affected checkboxes in column C.

Comment: Can anyone assist with this? I still get this issue.