# VBA Command Button keeps resizing when Saving PDF

Tags: vba, excel

I have the follow options selected in Excel 2010:

-Object positioning set to Don't move or size with cells
-Locked
-Locked Text

```
Sub SavePDF_Click()

Dim PDFDir As String
Dim ReportDate As Variant

ReportDate = Format(Worksheets(1).Range("C6").Value, "mmddyy")

PDFDir = "\\myserver\files\daily_reports\"

Sheets(Array("Cover_Page", "Blank_Page", "Assets", "Analytics")).Select

ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:= _
    PDFDir & "daily_reports_" & ReportDate & ".pdf", Quality:=xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=True, _
     IgnorePrintAreas:=False, OpenAfterPublish:=False

Sheets("Assets").Select
Worksheets("Assets").Activate

MsgBox ("PDF Saved")

End Sub
```

Comment: Check out this [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1573349/excel-the-incredible-shrinking-and-expanding-controls)

Comment: Also, this might help you [Link](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2519799)

Answer (score 0):

The links posted above by GMalc provided very valuable insight. My issue may be due to the files being on different servers than my local machine and some resolution differences may be causing the resizing.

WORKAROUND
In the sub I temporarily disabled screen updating and remained on the same sheet. This no longer causes the buttons to resize.