# Is it possible to address a shape with VBA code?

Tags: excel, vba

I am replacing all my ActiveX controls with Excel shapes, because of this [well know problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1573349/excel-the-incredible-shrinking-and-expanding-controls). Therefore I replaced each ActiveX Button with a rectangular shape assigning a macro to each shape:

[image]

**My question** is if I can address those 'shape buttons' with my vba code. Something simple like *change the backgroung color of the "Review Start" button* should be possible, right?

I'm thinking of something like:

```
Activesheet.shapes("Review Start").background.colorindex = 1
```

(This code is obviously not working)

Comment: There is no `Background` property for [Shape](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.shape), but if you name your shape "Review Start" (and not only text) you should be able to access it with `Shapes("Review Start")`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way is this. Assign a variable to the shape and then you can access its properties and methods easily. I'm not sure there's a way without using RGB.

By declaring the variable as `Shape` type, Intellisense will show you the properties and methods. Also you can use the [Object Browser](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/use-the-object-browser) (F2).

```
Sub x()

Dim s As Shape

Set s = ActiveSheet.Shapes("Review Start") 'better to specify a sheet name

With s
    .Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 255, 255)
    .TextFrame.Characters.Font.Color = vbBlack
    .TextFrame.Characters.Text = "Fred"
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: In addition, it's always good to do this way, then you can look at the locals window also whilst debugging.

Comment: Thank you so so much! In addition I'd like to know, how I can change the "Value" / "Caption" of the Button. I don't see any related properties in the list.

Comment: I've added to the code above. And remember to use more meaningful procedure and variable names than I have!