# Excel resizing buttons and fonts when display scale is not 100%

Tags: excel, vba

I have a sheet with VB buttons (using Form controls or ActiveX controls makes no difference).

When the display scale in windows is not 100%, after a button is down it resizes to something not the same size, as shown below (Export Forecast Data... button). When a different button is clicked, it pops back to normal size and the new button then gets this effect.

What you see below is 125%, but the bigger the scale, the worse it gets. In addition, as you can see, it is changing font sizes too.

If I save then reload, all buttons pressed end up resized to the smaller size they were after being clicked and do so badly, as third screenshot.

I have tried on many computers and they all have the same fault.

These have been Excel Office 365/2016.

Any ideas how to fix this? Also, I believe this may be linked to not just a scaling, but having two displays, one at 100% and the other at a different scale.

[image]

[image: isplay]

The effect of the resize after saving

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Excel: the Incredible Shrinking and Expanding Controls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1573349/excel-the-incredible-shrinking-and-expanding-controls)

Comment: Thanks. I managed to fix the font issue by checking 'lock aspect ratio' in the scale property, but nothing fixes the scaling. You'd think by now that if you used the form controls and not the activeX Microsoft might have fixed it by 2020. Or indeed found a way to just get rid of VBA and all the legacy crap and replace it...